# what happens when I execute fetch() on minimongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, fetch, minimongo

To query objects on [meteors](https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases) client-side mongodb implementation, I can use either

```
MyModel.find();
// produces a lot of attributes, not useful
```

or

```
MyModel.find().fetch();
// returns array containing my objects from type 'MyModel', e.g.
// [ { _id: "1", title: "some title", url: "some Url"__proto__: Object }, .. ]
```

If I don't use fetch, I get a lot of attributes I don't understand and which doesn't seem to be useful for me. I wonder what actually happens when I call the `fetch()` method. I was not able to find any docs concerning this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Collection.find();**

It finds the documents in a collection that match the selector and returns the cursor. In Meteor, `find()` is synchronous, if something changes in database, it will get reflect on UI aswell.

[Here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) is more details about `Collection.find()`

> **cursor.fetch();**

`fetch()` is to get all records from database at-ones from cursor. You can use fetch on cursor returned by `find()`. When you use fetch(), you will get all records in an array but you will not gets updates, i.e. runtime database changes will not reflected on returned data after execution.

[Here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) is more details about `cursor.fetch()`

> **What to use?**

If you need all documents and want to do some operations on it, then only `fetch()` is useful else, working on cursor is best.

**Conclusion**

Using Collection.find() is best, reliable and lightweight. But finally it is as per your application logic.

Comment: perfect, that's exactly the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

There is one more fundamental difference between `find` and `fetch` to keep in mind: `fetch` causes a deep copy operation of the whole cursor data. That eats CPU and memory.

Thus: do not use `fetch` if you do not need it! You only need it when passing data to 3rd party libraries like `d3` that do not understand what is a cursor and require a native JS array.

Comment: Yes and also for debugging it's useful

Comment: @BM, I like your answer, I have a query that, whether cursor uses shallow copy or deep copy?

Comment: It does a copy in which everything you get is really a copy and not a reference. So technically it is a deep copy.